# How to optimize the data read part of my code?

Tags: java, algorithm, input, graph, io

I am working on an algorithm problem recently. I think my program performs not well when reading data with too many lines, could anybody help me to optimize the reading part? Thanks a lot.

sample input

```
5 15 5
2 5 181
1 5 98
4 2 49
3 2 262
4 3 26
2 4 192
5 1 221
2 2 254
4 4 233
1 5 44
5 4 67
4 2 214
1 1 47
1 1 118
5 4 3
```

my code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
            
         StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
            
            st.nextToken();
            int vertices = (int) st.nval;
            st.nextToken();
            int numEdges = (int) st.nval;
            st.nextToken();
            int sourceVertex = (int) st.nval - 1;
            int source;
            int destination;
            int weight;
            
            Graph graph = new Graph(vertices);
            
            for(int i = 0; i < numEdges; i++) {
                st.nextToken();
                source = (int) st.nval - 1;
                st.nextToken();
                destination = (int) st.nval - 1;
                st.nextToken();
                weight = (int) st.nval;
                graph.addEdge(source, destination, weight);
            }
            
            graph.dijkstra_GetMinDistances(sourceVertex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a buffer reader, the readline method. And then parse the resulting string to integer values.

Comment: Actually I used this method, but it turned out to be slower than this one.